# ANTLR: SQL engine - specifics beyond the AST

Tags: antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

have always wanted to get to grips a little with Compilers and DSL's and have been trying to dabble with a SQL like engine specifically for log files.

.. I realize that there are many of these out there already, but please remember that part (well, most) of the excersize is as an excuse to learn this stuff.

I feel that I've hit a mental block though, and was hoping people could help me pass it..

Lots of the texts that I have read focus on grammar construction, which is fine - but I'm confused about the leap from having/constructing an AST to actually making it do something useful.

I have been reading the chapter in [this book](http://pragprog.com/book/tpdsl/language-implementation-patterns) on interpreted languages - the one about the 'pie' language - as this seems to have the most meat about this specific part of building a language.

if I had to code something like

```
select x,y from "c:\temp\foo.txt" where x=1 delimited by {Commas}
```

Assume I have loaded the contents of the file into an ArrayList to make things easy, Then would I be building an external tree walker to traverse my AST and shuffle elements into intermediate storage (if they matched `x=1`) - finally printing out the last buffer which would be the result set.

Looking forward to any guidance on offer.

Cheers, Ace

Comment: I made a few blog posts about the stage *after* creating an AST (ie. actually evaluating/interpreting). See: http://bkiers.blogspot.com/2011/03/creating-your-own-programming-language.html

Comment: thanks bart - that certainly gets me on my way